When I copy and paste long expressions into a text editor, they get pasted over multiple new lines. How do I stop this?
issue:
Consider the following expression:
"123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100"

When I use the 'Copy As' > Input Text option in Mathematica (the default copy method) and paste into a text editor, the text is frustratingly split over multiple lines like this:
"123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839\
4041424344454647484950515253545556575859606162636465666768697071727374\
75767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100"

Going to the Finder menu on mac and clicking: Edit>Show Clipboard, I can see that Mathematica is to blame:

context:
My use case is copying code from my notebook to a text editor using the standard keyboard shortcuts.
This is a very basic workflow.
Question: How to stop copied expressions from being split over multiple lines?
Clues:
I notice that when I use CopyToClipboard[expr] or "Copy As Plaintext" (using the Cell Bracket) this issue does not occur.

Alternative Question:
How do you move code from the notebook to an editor (like VSCode or emacs) without this text wrapping phenomenon happening?

The following fixed this for me:

open init.m:

SystemOpen[FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Kernel", "init.m"}]]


Add the following line:

SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, "ExportTypesetOptions" -> {"PageWidth" -> 3000}]


or
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, {"PageWidth" -> 3000, "ExportTypesetOptions" -> {"PageWidth" -> 3000}}];


restart your session with Quit



If you really want to have no line breaks, you can replace 2000 with Infinity :)

Setting "PageWidth" -> Infinity would be better.

@Domen, @MarcoB, strangely when I change 2000 to Infinity, it doesn't work for me on mac. Bug?

@Conor That's odd. It seems to work for me (Win10-64, MMA 14.1).
